# How to package and execute a binary in background with cordova in android?

Tags: android, cordova, executable, child-process, capacitor

Trying to run an executable .so file with cordova in the background. I have a "lib" folder which contains the folders "arm64-v8a", "ameabi-v7a" and "x86_64" These three folders contain the executable .so file for the matching archetecture (arm etc.)

How would I package them into the cordova app? Can I simply put the "lib" directory into the "www" directory of the cordova app? Then build it and then copy it to a place from where I could execute it in android? What is such a place / folder and how would I do it?
Then how would I run it in the background and stop it when the cordova app is full closed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting the files in the www folder will do nothing, you should put the files in the native project, in the proper folder, but that's not really recommended in Cordova apps, you should create a plugin that copies and uses the files.

The plugin should have a `plugin.xml` file that copies the `.so` files to the native project, something like:

```
<platform name="android">
    <source-file src="libs/arm64-v8a/yourlibrary.so" target-dir="src/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a/" />
    <source-file src="libs/armeabi-v7a/yourlibrary.so" target-dir="src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/" />
    <source-file src="libs/x86_64/yourlibrary.so" target-dir="src/main/jniLibs/x86_64/" />
</platform>
```

Comment: does this also run the .so file? It must be run as background process.

Comment: No, just copies it to your project. A .so is just a library, you need to write code that uses the library.

Answer (score 1):

Cordova is just a WebView. The scope of what you can do with that is rather limited. Everything from unstable background execution to the fact that you do not have direct access to native code.

What you could do is create a separate Cordova plugin that executes it on android. On the `npm` level, inside the module, you can ensure that the binary is copied over and plan its execution on the native level.

You do not even need to write the Cordova bridge, as `onPause` and `onResume` can be handled entirely natively. The Cordova layer doesn't even need to know about it.

- **Plugin development guide**: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/10.x/guide/hybrid/plugins/
- Have a look at how other plugins have handled copying native binaries: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-scanbot-sdk